# How to render a HTML comment in React?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

Currently the render method can only return a single element/component. See: [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127)

In the discussion under that ticket some suggest to wrap multiple elements returned from a React component in a HTML comment so that the wrapping component is ignored by the browser, e.g.:

```
<A>
    <B></B>
    <Fragment>
        <C></C>
        <D></D>
    </Fragment>
    <E></E>
</A>
```

would render to:

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <!--<fragment data-reactid="">-->
        <c></c>
        <d></d>
    <!--</fragment>-->
    <e></e>
</a>
```

But how to actually create a component that renders just HTML comment? In other words, how the render function of the 'fragment' component in the example above could look like?

Comment: The person posting that comment didn't understand how React works. Note that none of the ones who do suggested it would work. For one thing, it doesn't address the core issue; the result is four nodes (a comment node, two element nodes, and then a comment node), not a single node.

Comment: My understanding was that the Fragment's render function would only return the Fragment component with two children components 'c' and 'd'. Therefore the closing tag '/fragment' in the second comment. Also, it seems that technique has been used to implement a fragment component in mwiencek/react fork in commit dcc972c414, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Hey @Greg, I hope my solution helps. Sorry that I had to edit/refactor it a few times. I apologize if you were notified too many times, while I made all these changes.

Comment: Just FYI for future readers -- since 2017 when the React.Fragment API was added, the *motivation* for this question has evaporated.  Use a fragment, not html comments ;-).

Comment: I have come to the unfortunate conclusion that it is not possible to output a simple HTML comments in React JSX. The best of the solutions below inject the HTML comment inside a DIV element.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This solution uses some voodoo `outerHTML` magic to replace the injected element with the comment node achieving the result. Nice trick!
`useEffect(() => {
        ref.current.outerHTML = \`<!--${text}-->\`;
    }, [text]);
    return (<script ref={ref} type="text/placeholder" />);`

https://dirask.com/posts/React-create-HTML-comment-comment-D7R861

Answer (score 30):

This is what I have ended up with in one of my recent projects:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ReactComment extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        text: PropTypes.string,
        trim: PropTypes.bool
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        trim: true
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        let el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(el);
        el.outerHTML = this.createComment();
    }

    createComment() {
        let text = this.props.text;

        if (this.props.trim) {
            text = text.trim();
        }

        return `<!-- ${text} -->`;
    }

    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
}

export default ReactComment;
```

So you can use it like this:

```
<A>
    <B></B>
    <ReactComment text="<fragment>" />
        <C></C>
        <D></D>
     <ReactComment text="</fragment>" />
    <E></E>
</A>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I understand this code it doesn't answer my question. My aim isn't to render a comment in React but to return from a render function a single element, which renders two comments, one above and one below its children. In other words, I should be able to use it like this: `<Fragment><C /><D /></Fragment>` and it should render the children with two comments, one above and one below, as in the example in my question.

Comment: cool. creating custom component for comment.

Answer (score 15):

You can do it with the following component, it is simple and functional but it has the drawback of having to wrap your comment in a HTML node i.e.
a "div" because it makes use of the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute:

```
    const ReactComment = ({ text }) => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<!-- ${text} -->` }}/>
}
```

Then, you use it like so:

```
<ReactComment text={'My beautiful <b>HTML</b> comment'}/>
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's another novel approach if you need this to work with SSR.

Here's a `MaxWidth` component I am using with my react-based email tool called [Myza](https://github.com/teamcurri/myza).

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

export const MaxWidth = ({ maxWidth = 0, className, children }: IMaxWidthProps) => {
  const renderedChildren = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    <div className={className} style={{ maxWidth: `${maxWidth}px`, margin: '0 auto' }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    <!--[if mso]><center><table><tr><td width="${maxWidth}"><![endif]-->
    ${renderedChildren}
    <!--[if mso]> </td></tr></table></center><![endif]-->
  ` }}
  />
}
```

Comment: I assume this won't work for conditional tags inside head elements since `div` cannot be used inside `head`.

Answer (score 6):

I have seen some answers here say to use a syntax similar to `{'<!-- comment -->'}` which would simply display `<!-- comment -->` as a `<p>` on your browser, it may work if you do the same thing with a ref and then set the `ref.current.outerHTML = '<!-- comment -->'`, but that is extremely tedious and requires useEffect, useRef and a lot of extra code. And you still need to create a throw away div that is replaced with the comment so unless you're going out of your way to try to trick users into thinking you added a comment (which if they know how to inspect a page and view comments then they most likely also know how to read the React JS that your sending too)

A very simple and compact solution that I have used when I want to add a comment is this:

```
<div style={{display:'none'}}>
    comment
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**HTML Comments in React**

To render comments in React (which is what I'm guessing most people are looking for when they come to this question), I use a react component which I have in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/JonathonRichardson/e9aa0f79aaaefc97d4a8b415a09f075b).  It was based off of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41131326/4339894) by Alex Zinkevych, but with the following improvements:

- Updates to props now trigger the component to update, so the comment can be more dynamic
- The component cleans up after itself
- The div is hidden before being swapped out for the comment node
- (Code Style) React Ref used instead of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)`, which is the recommended way of interacting with the DOM elements, according to React's documentation.

I linked to the gist above, but I've also copied the content at the time of this writing below, but you might want to see if there's any revisions on the gist, since I will fix any bugs I might find and post as revisions to the Gist.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

interface IProps {
    text: string;
}

export class HTMLComment extends React.Component<IProps> {
    private node: Comment;
    private ref$rootDiv = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);

        this.node = window.document.createComment(props.text);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.ref$rootDiv && this.ref$rootDiv.current) {
            let divElement = this.ref$rootDiv.current;

            // Tell React not to update/control this node
            ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(divElement);

            // Replace the div with our comment node
            this.ref$rootDiv.current.replaceWith(this.node);
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IProps) {
        if (prevProps.text !== this.props.text) {
            this.node.textContent = this.props.text;
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.node.remove();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                ref={this.ref$rootDiv}
                style={{
                    display: 'none',
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

**Answering the Actual Question**

However, as the OP noted in a comment on Alex's post, this doesn't actually answer the question.  For a single component that renders comments before and after the children, we can use the HTMLComment component defined above and compose a new component:

```
interface IHTMLCommentWrapperProps {

}

const HTMLCommentWrapper: React.FunctionComponent<IHTMLCommentWrapperProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <HTMLComment text={`<fragment data-reactid="">`} />
            {props.children}
            <HTMLComment text={`</fragment>`} />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Now, we can put all this together into one script.  [Here is that source code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQoksiK62eMAIgPICycREuUocAtABMStOgwB2MLFAJ4scAJIAFYmHQBvOnENwFADxgAuOKhhRgsgOb0AvjKwmm8XABs06ABIAKrwAMgDCJCBY8nBuCrLibFQwAHTh4BCyUTAAPJraqAB8cPpGcGC2AG7ICnCyEOJYlmmR8vSl5cBVNZQEACTEEFydcAC8mEnJuCIK2ATZgSGcnQCiXlgtMAUAFACU9AZGuBnWUACu%20NBb5RA6lnk3qDvFB6WGqKdgilf5ezKvRjAABbAVDJOoNUZwADudkkUOSklwpw2k2mWGaWW%20D2Sphgv1KLhecCO6Uy8iW4l4EFO8l2z3%20hmABDgWyBIOSPX6EEGSwqcAAZPzjMDQZyBkMKpNTlBKPIniUGaU1vBxCs1htIWzRVg%20uLeVKZVl9orSgB6U1wAJYLxecYcWqDYwQOAfcTVLCmo7yYi2rUOhpExXsfA8XjJGkganyNKQMkwACCMAAcvUsFtVRVVussr9AwzzeMwD5cKogaoM9DgEC4NSoMSIll-Vg8-8tRydVyeZ0DbKUpQiyoAOpVwGskVg1P4hkuAl-Q4kWNZCkAVTAboU3ywFS0DzuO508pbcCZLPKW-3oNxcAAhCMxm3rjocbFDyaAePwVhn2ZwvJG-fx0fS9YjaaciUJUoSUXeRhxtZdZEjGkYDpBVWw-VN20jCo0ynQwIKMWUGigFCj0oGBpVkFkj1KbIM2ohkehGXQ2zFbkJRnN9XmsABPNYmNQzj-lVVAB24ywyDqTIyAAGno-4nA4t9TQKI9cLgFxCTsBQlBUdQFjCBsYKgZAwE%20KAL2eOhCS9aw4H0jEjJMszLGDFIADEaXwYAMhjDIslyezDJgQdjNMxQLyKMYsQPUYigEsiKKoxVslc5I3OM%20wNhUwT5iCAyQA1XEmIAA2yIhkEyxt12QUQRC88QRgAIkagpiqcOBlLk4ogMmYEvHEWVFJNXKQgc%20Ait0UrTXKyr5Fa9rOuS01UvSiqsqJHYrJkBpvGQSg4HsLwIAAI2QW0BNkZBIhE3SACkAGUAA16VeLTFGUEt1G9OxUGAXAsw2PQjzIXAyBciZOCwGBkGANZxH0i8UomfTExsYBjtOBRUBG4IAayAppLsvK8bm0D-jIcQwbtfBkkh6HYaweG8sR1KUZgNGMaxnGSc2Qn9J5goydeMgsCp1K6ZhuGEfyJGOGSNmOcxrBsf59V8b54m1dJvMho0mQbPgeNwbljzZC8nyFz86IoqAp4RjiuAEqgSjsmQApdB63A%20oGqInGyU03fUugDbgAAhY2adN83ZF8uNIWix5YuKR2ocS7Jjvdz3vcG-2M6DkPQgj9zPJgbyY8tuObZ%20JPdBT8jnbgbJcEz-Jethn3ZD9z0ihcEPOCLtKS7L2P-1Pav7eTp2XfEFvsS99uc9NGf8%20OeBlgHqPS4t0lR4Tu2HanxusFnp95-6xfj6D4PV7geNTI3oft%20g%20Aov3l7DEPrYj2yeNss47JQ4FH9oArqOMxohScooP%20glDDZFCEA008Cuo0U4Ag1BoDTSBQKlkCBYUoDQOGssBBRDv6ml-htLadBlQxC8J2F%20cBETIiyMkewUMeah24mocQWwKBJFEE5MgvwTxbGtHQ18RhXKhnbPEL4P9TIdQJjQsRzg6BAA) over at the Typescript playground, as well as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/JonathonRichardson/f38be1add30a3d5fee915f7961db4fc2) (it's large and repeast the components detailed above, so I won't copy that code directly into this answer.

We can copy the compiled javascript into the snippet below:

```js
class HTMLComment extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref$rootDiv = React.createRef();
        this.node = window.document.createComment(props.text);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.ref$rootDiv && this.ref$rootDiv.current) {
            let divElement = this.ref$rootDiv.current;
            // Tell React not to update/control this node
            ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(divElement);
            // Replace the div with our comment node
            this.ref$rootDiv.current.replaceWith(this.node);
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.text !== this.props.text) {
            this.node.textContent = this.props.text;
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.node.remove();
    }
    render() {
        return (React.createElement("div", { ref: this.ref$rootDiv, style: {
                display: 'none',
            } }));
    }
}
const HTMLCommentWrapper = (props) => {
    return (React.createElement(React.Fragment, null,
        React.createElement(HTMLComment, { text: `<fragment data-reactid="">` }),
        props.children,
        React.createElement(HTMLComment, { text: `</fragment>` })));
};
const A = (props) => { return React.createElement("a", null, props.children); };
const B = (props) => { return React.createElement("b", null, props.children); };
const C = (props) => { return React.createElement("c", null, props.children); };
const D = (props) => { return React.createElement("d", null, props.children); };
const E = (props) => { return React.createElement("e", null, props.children); };
const App = () => {
    return (React.createElement(A, null,
        React.createElement(B, null),
        React.createElement(HTMLCommentWrapper, null,
            React.createElement(C, null),
            React.createElement(D, null)),
        React.createElement(E, null)));
};
let el$root = document.getElementById('react-app');
if (el$root) {
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), el$root);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react-app"/>
```

If you run this snippet and inspect the HTML, you'll see the following:

[image]

Comment: I assume this won't work for SSR since we're using `componentDidMount` and `window`.

Comment: Depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  If you want the server side rendered pages to have the comments inline, no.

Comment: However, if you're `ReactDOM.hydrate()`ing the page, you'll be able to see the comments in the inspector once the lifecycle methods have fired.

You could get comments in the initial SSR by using hidden elements (e.g. `<div hidden />`), possibly using a custom element (`<ns-comment hidden />`), and you could emit that for SSR, and use the lifecycle methods to replace the custom element with real HTML comments at hydration/run time, if you want.

Kind of depends on why you want the comments.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21601

Answer (score 3):

I feel the need to post [my answer](https://gist.github.com/zomars/4c366a0118a5b7fb391529ab1f27527a) here since this is where I first landed when searching for this.

I know this is a hack but for my use case this allows me to inject arbitrary html inside `head` tags:

```
const DangerousRawHtml = ({ html = "" }) => (
  <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `</script>${html}<script>` }} />
);
```

Usage:

```
const EmailHead = ({ title = "" }) => {
  return (
    <head>
      <title>{title}</title>
      <DangerousRawHtml html={`<!--[if !mso]><!--><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!--<![endif]-->`} />
    </head>
  )
}
```

The output will leave some empty `script` tags along the way which is not optimal but it works:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script></script>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <script></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Also if you're planning to use `renderToStaticMarkup`, you can do this to cleanup the empty scripts:

```js
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<MyRootComponent />)
  // Remove `<DangerousRawHtml />` injected scripts
  .replace(/<script><\/script>/g, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the similar solution to [render curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47342071/3416774), I guess we can use HTML characters to substitute them:

```html
&lt!-- comment --&gt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on React 16.8+ you may use a small functional component which lets you provide a text property and render an html comment.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

const ReactComment = ( props ) => {
    const el = useRef();
    useEffect( () => {
        el.current.outerHTML = `<!-- ${props.text} -->`;
    }, [] );
    return (
        <div ref={el}/>
    );
};

export default ReactComment;
```

You may then use it like so

```
<A>
    <B></B>
    <ReactComment text="<fragment>" />
        <C></C>
        <D></D>
     <ReactComment text="</fragment>" />
    <E></E>
</A>
```

Comment: This solution seems to not work when using `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`

Comment: It will also crash when react is trying to unmount the component because it can't find the child node that it is expecting in the DOM.

Comment: doesnt't crash during unmounting for me, but interested in any other drawbacks

Comment: Did you use Prettier for the ReactComment component?

Comment: @FibreFoX you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72438617/6297100) for a solution compatible with `redenerToStaticMarkup`

Answer (score 0):

This works, and gives you proper comment tag, rather than a div…

```
useEffect(() => {
    const c = document.createComment(`Hi there!`);
    document.appendChild(c);
    return () => document.removeChild(c);
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a functional component with a file name Comment.js

Import jquery to select divs using their class selectors, in combination with using native javascript document.createComment

Use props to pass the text to be used in the comments, as well as, the names of the divs to select:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

const Comment = (props) => {
  const commentMakerBegin = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const beginComment = document.createComment(props.beginComment);
      const firstElement = $('.' + props.beforeDiv);
      firstElement.before(beginComment);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const commentMakerEnd = (event) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const endComment = document.createComment(props.endComment);
      const secondElement = $('.' + props.afterDiv);
      secondElement.after(endComment);
    }, 1000);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {commentMakerBegin()}
      {props.children}
      {commentMakerEnd()}
    </>
  );
};

export default Comment;
```

The props.children renders whatever is between your custom component tags:

```
{props.children}
```

Whether you type a string like 'Your components here' or '`<C /><D />`' it will render what you type between the opening and closing tags.

In the component that you would like to use the newly created Comment component, import it, followed by passing the text through props that you would like to use for the opening and closing comments

The following image is how I render comments before and after my two modals - consumer-modal and policy-modal respectively.

[image: You can see in the console that the comments have been added]

In my App.js file, I import the Comments component and use it in the following manner, which results in the aforementioned screen shot:

```
     <Comment
        beforeDiv='consumer-modal'
        afterDiv='policy-modal'
        beginComment='modal begins'
        endComment='modal ends'
      >
        <ConsumerModal
          title='testing'
          content={<ConsumerModalContent />}
          onClose={cnsmrModalHandler}
        ></ConsumerModal>
        <PolicyModal
          title='my policy'
          content={<PolicyModalContent />}
          onClose={policyModalHandler}
        />
      </Comment>
```

Answer (score -13):

**Edit:** For those who found this answer useful, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40372667/6473505) instead!

The posted problem is not asking for comment style in React!

---

Use curly brackets, such that you can use javascript comment `/* */`.

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    {/*<fragment data-reactid="">*/}
        <c></c>
        <d></d>
    {/*</fragment>*/}
    <e></e>
</a>
```

Comment: 6 upvotes for an answer that doesn't even provide a solution for the problem posed?!  This is just how to put comments in your component code, but (like me) the OP wants to *output* comments into his rendered html !

Comment: This will not render the comments into html comments `<!-- comment -->`. They won't even come out in minified source since a transpiler will take them out