# How to add visible HTML comment in JSX?

Tags: html, reactjs, comments, jsx

I am using ReactJS and I have a requirement to add visible HTML comment (in html source) in JSX but I am not sure how to do that.

This comment is needed by a third party vendor to do some processing on the html between the comments.

```
<!-- trans_disable_start -->
<div> testing </div>
<!-- trans_disable_end-->
```

I tried the below options but the comment is not visible in html source.

```
{/* <!-- trans_disable_start -->*/}
```

Tried using this library - `react-render-html`

```
{renderHTML('<!-- trans_disable_start -->')}
```

Any ideas / thoughts is appreciated.

**Update 1:**

I tried to use the below JS library but that doesnt work since I am using the server side rendering and I see the below value in page source on initial load (Rather than comment)

https://github.com/optimalisatie/react-jsx-html-comments

```
<react-comment data-reactid="18">trans_disable_start</react-comment>
```

Comment: Try without the curly braces. E.g. for example `/* test */`

Comment: Tried without curly braces but got the parse error. Errr: Unexpected token

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render a HTML comment in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015336/how-to-render-a-html-comment-in-react)

Comment: Found it after I sent the answer. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Also [this](https://github.com/optimalisatie/react-jsx-html-comments) might help too

Answer (score 8):

I think `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` can work for you.

**Example**

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "<!-- some comment -->"}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your IDE is giving you code line syntax errors (not runtime) after entering:

```
{/* This is a comment */}
```

Run your code anyway and see if it works. If it does, your IDE is the problem.

I recently reported this problem to my IDE developer and they promptly released a new upgrade and the problem went away. (Not that they upgraded solely because of this but they squeezed the fix in nevertheless. Although ReactJS/JSX has been around for a while, it's still novel enough to slip by even the best of em).