# How to Inject HTML Comments Containing PageMap into the Head Element using Next.js without extra wrapper tags

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, seo

I'm trying to inject a custom HTML comment with google PageMap into the  element of my Next.js application. The content I want to add is structured like this:

```
<!--
<PageMap>
    <DataObject type="document">
        <Attribute name="title">The Biomechanics of a Badminton Smash</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="author">Avelino T. Lim</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="description">The smash is the most explosive and aggressive stroke in Badminton...</Attribute>
        ...
    </DataObject>
    ...
</PageMap>
-->
```

Constraints:

Acording to google docs about that I can't use any extra wrapper tags like .
I'm not using any external libraries to achieve this. Only core Next.js and React features, also this should be working on SSR so i want to find solution without using useEffect.

I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this as google suggested. Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.

So far i tried solutions from here : [How to render HTML Comment in React(Next.js) Without Wrapper Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77161373/how-to-render-html-comment-in-reactnext-js-without-wrapper-element)

and also tried to use extra package like: https://github.com/Zneider/react-html-comment#readme
but this also doesn't work at all.