# How to comment an attribute in .tsx files?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jsx

Given the following JSX code:

```
<div className="my-class"></div>
```

How can I comment out the `className="my-class"`?

- `/*className="my-class"*/` does not work
- `{/* className="my-class" */}` does not work (`TS1005:'...' expected`)

Comment: You can't, if I remember correctly. Which is a real shame. Hope someone tells me I'm an idiot and proves me wrong on this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `/*className="my-class"*/ does not work`

[Works fine](http://typestyle.io/play/#src=%3Cdiv%20/*className=%22my-class%22*/%3EHello%3C/div%3E): 
[image]

You can also do:

```
<div 
  // className="my-class"
  >Hello</div>
```

Comment: You are right! This is a bug in Webstorm! (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26630)

Answer (score 0):

[image: comment in tsx file]

Works for me fine. We use this way like this in my team.