# React: how to comment HTML inside a render method

Tags: reactjs

(Sorry if too obvious and/or dup, couldn't find original one...)

How should I be able to comment out TodoTitle below? I tried with `<!--...-->, //, /*...*/` with no luck.

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todo-app">
        <TodoTitle />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS - how to use comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766441/reactjs-how-to-use-comments)

Answer (score 7):

You can comment `{/* comment */}` in JSX.

Answer (score 4):

Can you not just use {/* stuff */} ?