# How do I pass a prop that contains the image location to image source when rendering many images in a flatlist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, react-native, react-redux

My code below accepts `inputPhotoLocation` as a prop. `inputPhotoLocation` contains a list of image source locations (which have been retrieved from a file containing a list). I need a way to pass these to my image source. I have been able to pass the locations directly in the text box with success.

```
function SelectionBoxComponent({inputPhotoLocation, inputText, onPress}) {
    return (

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
            <View style={styles.box}>
                <View style={styles.circularPhoto}>
                    <Image style={{height:"100%", width:"100%", borderRadius:70,
                        borderWidth:0, source={require(inputPhotoLocation)}}} ></Image> {/* Here I need to insert the list items */}
                </View>

                <AppText style={styles.textStyle} onPress={console.log(inputText)} >
                    {inputText}</AppText>

            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

My `inputPhotoLocation` prop contains this:

`./assets/GroupImages/football.jpg`

`../assets/GroupImages/valley.jpg`

`../assets/GroupImages/usa.jpg`

`../assets/GroupImages/playstation.jpg`

`../assets/GroupImages/pc.jpg`

I am able to pass these locations as text outputs successfully. However, I can't figure out how to pass these in the image source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```jsx
      <Image
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          borderRadius: 70,
          borderWidth: 0,
          {/* The source prop is not a style prop */}
          source={require(inputPhotoLocation)
        }}></Image>



      <Image
        {/* The source prop is Image prop */}
        source={require(inputPhotoLocation)
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          borderRadius: 70,
          borderWidth: 0
        }}></Image>
```

Comment: This seems to be unbalanced - one extra "`{`" for each block (also indicated by the weird syntax highlighting). Shouldn't `{require(inputPhotoLocation)` be `{require(inputPhotoLocation)}` (an extra "`}`" at the end)? (This should be independent of the [comment character sequence requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30766542).)

Comment: To be clear, the main concern is the syntax highlighting on this Stack Overflow page. Either the code should be fixed or the syntax highlighting should be turned off (e.g. with [code fence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-wok/184109#184109) \`\`\`lang-none ... \`\`\`).

Comment: Is the sample code here valid?

Comment: Yes, the lower code is valid. I post both variants  to make it clear what is wrong and which line cause the issue.

Comment: But the original code is not unbalanced - it is `{{...source={require(inputPhotoLocation)}}}` (not `{{...source={require(inputPhotoLocation)}}`)

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer? It *seems* like you have removed one `}` compared to the source code example in the question (near "`source={require`"). Maybe there is a good reason for making the code invalid (the code in the question is not invalid in this respect), but it ought to be explained.

Comment: Or in other words, why would invalid code/markup be part of an answer to the question?